# Application crashes with TargetInvocationException when entering view for second time

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

Whenever i enter any of my apps views for first time, everything is working as expected. Problems occur when i navigate back to previous view with androids built in back button.

As for example, lets imagine i have view X and Y.

1. View X is loaded on app start with no problem.
2. Click button which navigates me to view Y.
3. Click Android back button which navigates me back to view X.
4. Clicking the same button crashes the application.

In my case view X coresponds to "ReservationViewModel" and Y to "ReservationDetailsViewModel", but the issue occurs in all of my views

When the exception gets thrown, output console contains several logs:

```
2021-06-19 02:09:04 [TRACE] (MvxForms) PresentationAttribute not found for ReservationDetailsViewModel. Assuming ContentPage presentation
2021-06-19 02:09:04 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) No view model association found for candidate view StartActivity
**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:** 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

2021-06-19 02:09:04 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) No view model association found for candidate view StartActivity
```

Interesting enough, everything is fine if i would navigate back from view Y to view X with IMvxNavigationService. The problem occurs only with the back button

Comment: The issue lied in Syncfusions TitleView. Changing it for our own top bar fixed this problem